# idleTimerDisabled not working with (Autonomous) Single App Mode

Tags: ios, ios12

We have a kiosk app where we use `idleTimerDisabled` to keep the screen from turning off during the working hours, and let it switch off in the evening.

I do this with a timer created in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method:

```
self.screenLockTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(setupScreenLock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

-

```
- (void)setupScreenLock {
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *closingDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateBySettingHour:17 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:currentDate options:0];
    BOOL isOpeningHours = [currentDate compare:closingDate] == NSOrderedAscending;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = isOpeningHours;
}
```

This used to work fine until we started using **Autonomous Single App Mode**. Now the screen no longer turns off in the evening. Is there an explanation (and a workaround) for this? I know that there is a bug in iOS 12 where `idleTimerDisabled` no longer works with Guided Access, but I haven't seen reports on similar issues with Single App Mode.

Comment: I actually ended up with an identical problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing yet. I suspect it is a bug similar to that with idleTimerDisabled and guided access.

Comment: Just some additional info for you. I am actually able to get sleep timer to work if I pick it up and cause an orientation change... Which is still useless for a kiosk app.

Answer (score 1):

Triggering a native operation might "fix" the problem. I was able to resolve my issues using the code below.

Try using the following code:

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = isOpeningHours;

    // Guided access idle timer fix
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:textField]; // self.view or whatever relevant view is accessible.
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked like a charm! In our testing, plugging the device into charger also pulled the device (SpringBoard most likely) out of this "locked" state, but this also seems to work around it reliably. For now...

Answer (score 0):

Our approach was to reset the idle timer, wich is not disabled by resetting the idleTimerDisabled:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 840, repeats: true, block: { timer in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
             UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
             UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
       }
 })
```

This also works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that finally works (It's in the app swift file):

```
import SwiftUI                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                    
@main                                                                                                                                                               
struct TestApp: App {                                                                                                                                             
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase                                                                                                                       
    var body: some Scene {                                                                                                                                          
        WindowGroup {                                                                                                                                               
            ContentView()                                                                                                                                           
        }.onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in                                                                                                                    
            if newValue == .inactive || newValue == .background {                                                                                                   
                UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                                       
            if newValue == .active {                                                                                                                                
                UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                               
}
```